# Specifying legend location in folium

Tags: python, leaflet, legend, choropleth, folium

I have a few choropleth maps in one Leaflet map using folium. However, in my output, my legends all congregate underneath one another and on one side where it blocks the 'control zoom' icon.

Is there a way to alter the location of my legend(s) or only have one activated at a time?

Image of result:

[image]

Code of

```
NYC_coords = (40.7, -73.8) # specifying our location data
flm_map = flm.Map(location = NYC_coords, zoom_start = 10.3, tiles = 'cartodbpositron', zoom_control = True)# zoom level, tiles
dangerous_int = flm.FeatureGroup(name='Dangerous Intersections', control=True)
neighborhoods = flm.FeatureGroup(name = 'Neighborhoods', control = True)

dscore = flm.Choropleth(
        geo_data = nbhood, # json file, contains geometries
        data = nbhood_df, # dataframe used
        name = 'Danger Score',
        columns = ['Neighborhood','Danger Score Avg'], # columns to refer to for choropleth colors
        key_on = 'feature.properties.Neighborhood', # the key we are looking for to base 
        fill_color = 'Reds', # color ramp
        fill_opacity = 0.7,  
        line_opacity = 0.5,
        highlight = True,
        popup = flm.GeoJsonPopup(fields = ['Neighborhood', 'Danger Score Avg']),
        legend_name = 'Average Danger Score',
        smooth_factor = 0.2).add_to(flm_map) 
motor_inj = flm.Choropleth(
        geo_data = nbhood, # json file, contains geometries
        data = nbhood_df, # dataframe used
        name = 'Motor Injuries',
        columns = ['Neighborhood','Motor Vehicle Injuries'], # columns to refer to for choropleth colors
        key_on = 'feature.properties.Neighborhood', # the key we are looking for to base 
        fill_color = 'BuPu', # color ramp
        fill_opacity = 0.7,  
        line_opacity = 0.5,
        popup = flm.GeoJsonTooltip(fields = ['Neighborhood', 'Motor Vehicle Injuries']),
        highlight = True,
        legend_name = 'Motor Vehicle Injuries(total)',
        smooth_factpr = 0.2,
        show = False).add_to(flm_map)

flm.LayerControl('topright', collapsed = True).add_to(flm_map)
display(flm_map)
```

Comment: This doesn't quite answer your question, but you can disable the zoom controls on your map (while still being able to zoom using the scroll wheel) by passing `zoom_control=False` as an argument when you instantiate your mapping object.